# I'm trying to send a form data to the server using fetch post method but it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, fetch

```
let klantInfo = {
  Voornaam: voornaam,
  Achternaam: achternaam,
  Wachtwoord: myWachtwoord,
  EmailAdres: email,

}


let SendData = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  if (inputSucceeded) {
    window.onload = function() {
      postRequest();
    }

    function postRequest() {
      const messageHeaders = new Headers({ // (1)
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })

      fetch(apiUrl, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(klantInfo),
          headers: messageHeaders
        })
        .then(function validateResponse(res) {
          return res;
        })
        .then(function readResponseAsText(response) {
          return response;
        })
        .then(function logResult(result) {
          return result;
        })
        .catch(function logError(error) {
          return error;
        });
    }

    function readResponseAsText(response) {
      console.log(response.text()); // (1)
    }
  } else {
    alert("Niet alle tekst zijn gevuld");
    return;
  }
}
btnRegisteren.addEventListener('click', SendData)
```

Comment: Please write the problem.

Comment: The function SendData doesn't get executed. It is completely ignored as I click on the button.

Comment: To the question (wrong execute write the code and the respondent guess what your problem).

Comment: Please read about [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see the entire picture of what's going on.